# Создание и управление версиями одной программы в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, fortran, version

у меня есть программа, которую я постоянно дорабатываю и изменяю, но иногда нужно откатываться назад. Как дать текущей версии кода свою версию, создавать новые версии и присваивать им номера, и, при необходимости, переключаться между ними? Компьютер доступа в интернет не имеет. Работаю в Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Используйте git.

Comment: Разве Git не для компьютеров, подключенных к интернету?

Comment: Git работает и без интернета. Сервер может заменять просто ещё одна такая же папка с проектом (указать путь  к папке вместо URL), или его может вообще не быть.

Comment: Не стоит путать git (систему контроля версий, которая работает автономно) и github (один из хостингов для дальних репозиториев git).

Comment: Всё, теперь понял, спасибо всем!